# How is volume equal to length of block here?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics

Here we have a block submerged in water.Density of water = 1000 and of air = 0.density of block = 800.

Then , we have written the equation for downward force = g * V * 800 - g{( Ax(amount of area of that block in air I.e x) * x(length of block)*0 + Ay (1000)(y)}.

I didn’t understand why is V = x+y here ?

I thought for a while over it and saw maybe that it is done in this way that :

V of block / area of block with y length.Now , even if that is done.How can we compare area of only y portion of block in water with whole volume of block?
[image]

Comment: If V refers to the volume of the block then V should be Area times the length (x+y).

Comment: @shahrozeshahab Right.It is not written there.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a mistake. The equation
$$(x+y)800 = Ay1000$$
should be
$$A(x+y)800 = Ay1000$$

Notice that the $A$ on the right side of the equation disappears in the next line:
$$8x + 8y =10y$$

Comment: Ok.Thank you very much.I got it now